# Notation: $g:2^{[2]}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ what is $2^{[2]}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

On Pg 28, Question 26 of [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=yI4Jx5Obr08C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=true) book, the author writes

> Define $g:2^{[2]}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by the rule $g(S) = |S|$
>   where $S$ is any subset of $[2]$. Write $g$ as a set of ordered pairs.

I don't need the answers, just what it means.

Comment: Generally books tend to have a notation index at the end, where they keep all the notations they use, where they were defined and sometimes a two-words description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that $[n]$ is the set of positive integers $\{ 1, 2, ... n \}$ and that for $S$ a set, $2^S$ is the set of all subsets of $S$. (The idea being that $|2^S| = 2^{|S|}$.)

Comment: I knew the notation for the power set but I hadn't seen $[n]$. Thanks.

Comment: $[n]$ is defined on page 2.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks. I was referring the book to lookup some topics, so I missed it.

Comment: @kuch: then why didn't you ask "what is $[2]$"?

Comment: Ill try to be more precise in the future.

Comment: @kuch nahi: There is a list of notation on page 385.